# Java/python using processBuilder

Tags: java, python, processbuilder, inter-process-communicat

Good evening all,
am running a python script inside java using processBuilder.
the python script returns a list and i dont know how to get it java and use it since all i can do for the moment with process builder is print errors or outputs.
is it possible to get the list in java as well.
Many thanks

Comment: what the script output looks like?

Answer (score 0):

From your scenario, you are looking for inter process communication.

You can achieve this using shared file. Your python script will write the output in text file, and your java program will read the same file.

Comment: That's what i used at first but for my scenario it is not a good idea.
for the moment am using the process input stream and i parse the output to get back the list am looking for .